# Get the real Class Type

Tags: java, class, casting

If I do something like this:

```
String s = "hello";
Class<?> c = s.getClass();
```

Then `c` is acutally a `Class` but in there is a `String`.
So how do I get a `String` Type back?

Because if I use:
`c.getClass()` I get obviously a `Class` Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, `Class<?> c` will refer to the object of Class of Type String. `Class<?> c` basically has some `metadata` about the String class.

```
    String s = "hello";
    Class<?> c =  s.getClass();
    String s1 = (String) c.newInstance();
```

Edited:

So, there are several methods available on the Class object to retrieve the information about the Class :

```
    Class#getName() //the name of the class or interface represented by this object with package name
    Class#getSimpleName() // returns only the name of the Class
```

For example:

```
String s = "hello";
Class<?> c =  s.getClass();
System.out.println("Name : "+c.getName());
System.out.println("Simple Name: "+c.getSimpleName());
System.out.println("Canonical Name: "+c.getCanonicalName());
System.out.println("Type Name : "+c.getTypeName());
```

You will get the output:

```
Name : java.lang.String
Simple Name: String
Canonical Name: java.lang.String
Type Name : java.lang.String
```

Note: As you can see the same return value you are getting for different methods (like getCanonicalName, getCanonicalName etc), it may not be same always to know difference please the link I have provided below.

Appart from that there are several methods available on the Class object to get the `metadata information` about the `class`. Please follow the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more info.

Comment: No I need the information of what Type is behind. I actually dont know that it's a `String`.

Comment: `.getName()` helped insted of using `.getClass()`
Thank you!

Comment: Note that `Class.newInstance()` is deprecated today.  `Constructor.newInstance()` is the recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

First : you can get the class instance from an object as an instance of a class is associated to a class (whereas the presence of the `getClass()` method in the `Object` class) but it doesn't work in the other way as the class is not associated to a specific instance of.

Second : to get the type, you don't care whether an unbounded wildcard is specified or not in the `Class` declared type as generics are erased at runtime.
The thing that matters is that information about the class associated (here `String`) to the `Class` object is known by the `Class` object itself.
So for example, you can write the one or the second :

```
Class<? extends String> c = s.getClass();
Class<?> c = s.getClass();
```

And in any case you will be able to retrieve the type String as you invoke :

```
String typeName = c.getTypeName(); // --> java.lang.String
String name = c.getName(); // --> java.lang.String
```